# Minimum of the integral is the integral of the minimum

Tags: real-analysis

Consider some smooth function g(x,y). I would like to find the function $h(x)$ which minimizes the following integral

$$
\int_a^b g(x, h(x))\; \mathrm{d}x
$$

Intuitively, I believe that the function which minimizes this integral (let's call it $h^{\mathrm{min}}(x)$), may be found by minimizing the integrand at each value of $x$. In other words, at all values of $x\in (a,b)$, $h^{\mathrm{min}}(x)$ satisfies

$$
g(x, h^{\min}(x)) \leq g(x,a). \forall a\in \mathbb{R}
$$

I would state this succinctly as: the minima of the sum is the sum of the minima. In other words, the optimal strategy for choosing $h$ is to choose it such that $g$ is as small as possible at every value of $x\in(a,b)$; this will minimize the value of the integral.

My question is: if this is correct, how would one go about proving it? It seems a relatively elementary result, at the level of a first course in analysis, but it's beyond my skill-set to prove.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming such a minimum exists (which is not necessarily the case), and
that the integral $\int_a^b g(x, h^{min}(x))\; dx$ exists (in a suitable sense, say Riemann or Lebesgue; again, this is not guaranteed), then for any other function $h$ for which
$\int_a^b g(x,h(x))\; dx$ exists we have $g(x, h^{min}(x)) \le g(x, h(x))$
for all $x$ so that
$$ \int_a^b g(x, h^{min}(x))\; dx \le \int_a^b g(x, h(x))\; dx $$

For an example where the minimum does not exist, take $g(x,y) = 1/(y^2+1)$.  Then $\int_0^1 g(x, h(x))\; dx$ can be arbitrarily close to $0$ but there is no $h$ that makes it $0$.

Comment: Thanks, that clarifies things! Is there a name for the result that $f \leq g$ everywhere implies $\int f \leq \int g$? I'd like to cite something (or somewhere) concrete if possible.

Comment: To answer my own question, I think this follows from the 'comparison theorem' (e.g. in Apostol).